# Do I need a desktop to run a GUI?

Tags: xorg, gui, window-manager, xfce

I am setting up a light weight VM, following the guide in the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)

What I want to be able to do is launch a GUI application. I don't need / want anything on the desktop.

First I installed xorg. But I can't launch a gui. The next step is to install a "Window Manager". So I installed xfce4, and then `startx` launches a desktop.

What do I need to launch a gui but not launch a desktop?

Comment: I suppose you could do this, but I wouldn't think it would be very comfortable running everything in the terminal...

Comment: @TheX That is a good point. While waiting for the answer to this question, I found that it was handy to have the standard desktop features around. However, when I am finished setting up this system, I'd like it to be a single-use VM for demonstrating the use of the software. Having everything minimal like this makes it easier to identify what additional features the software will need; most of these, like a text editor and bash shell, can be run from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question over at [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23059/5048), and got the following answer:

If you build the VM and use it as a server, then ssh with x11forwarding (e.g. `ssh -X`), then the system does not need a desktop or window manager, although the host will.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to control exactly what runs when you run `startx` you should create a `.xinitrc` file in your home directory.  If you make .xinitrc something very simple like:

```
xfwm4 &
xterm
```

Then `startx` will run with only a window manager and a terminal.

Comment: excellent. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

From gdm you can select **xterm (recovery console)** and it will give you a simple terminal runing on X. From it, you can start any gui app without the full desktop, like:

```
nautilus $HOME &
```

Since gnome is not running, the themes won't work so you'll see the application running in simple gtk (ugly but functional).

Remember to add & at the end so it returns to prompt in case you want to start other applications.

Also, if you install evilwm

```
sudo aptitude install evilwm
```

and run it fromt that xterm, also with the &, it will allow you to move the windows with Alt+click

```
evilwm &
nautilus &
whatever_program &
```

Comment: good advice on the evilwm, but I'd prefer not to install gdm, which itself is a gui.

Comment: Well, in fact you don't need gdm, you only need it to launch the xterm. If you prefer you can install lightdm or even better, not install any session manager and launch x from a tty with startx command. Once you get a terminal on X you can launch evilwm and other programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a clean minimal installation, install `openbox`, then run startx on startup. After this, you just need to right click the desktop to access the Openbox menu which should allow you to launch a xterm or any installed applications.

Openbox is very light and has little dependencies.

Answer (score -5):

why you don't install gnome it is easier !!!

---

Or if you still want xfce :
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/install-xfce-4-8-in-ubuntu-10-10-ppa/

Comment: Those are both heavy desktop environments, which he's explicitly trying to avoid. -1

Comment: what is the computer RAM in which you will install ?

Comment: @volvo it is not a matter of RAM, it is that I want to make an application-specific VM rather than a desktop.